# R: How to order bars manually in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly, tidyverse

how to order bars according to the sales within each category
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

```
df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","USA","USA"),
                  Category = c("A", "B","A","B"),
                  Sales = c(103, 192, 144, 110))

ggplot(df, aes(fill=Category, y=Sales, x=Origin)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + coord_flip()
```

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate, but I voted to reopen, since the linked duplicate only dealt with rearranging bars on the x axis, not rearranging the order of dodged bars.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Perhaps the simplest is to use `position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)`

Note also that you are using a couple of outdated idioms. `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is just a long way of writing `geom_col`, and you don't need to use `coord_flip`, since ggplot will know that you intended a horizontal bar plot if you just reverse the x and y aesthetics.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(fill = Category, x = Sales, y = Origin)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: @user4567794374545 can you edit your question to show an example of when the default ordering is correct? Thanks.

Comment: @user4567794374545 OK. It would be great if you could edit your question to show an example where the ordering of the bars is the right way round and reverse = TRUE won't work for you. It's going to be difficult to help you without seeing an example of this.

Comment: @user4567794374545 but that is exactly the line that needs to be fixed to give you the correct result. Can you explain why you need to keep that line? There are other solutions, but they make it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528065/how-to-order-subgroups-in-a-ggplot-barplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721536/changing-the-order-of-dodged-bars-in-ggplot2-barplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245294/ggplot2-ordering-dodged-columns.  there are so many duplicates to this type of question!

Comment: @tjebo I'm not sure any of these are quite what the OP was looking for (I thought it might be a more subtle question,  hence why I was asking for clarification). Anyway, in the absence of a clear explanation of why my answer or any of the duplicates don't work, I think your use of the dupe hammer is right here.